# ADO.Net Entity Model "EF Desinger from Database" ignored 1 column

Tags: c#, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I created an ADO.Net entity Data Model with "EF Desinger From Database" from my Maria DB.
Entity Framework 6 was used.

When i created the model from 47 tables all data was there but 1 table has 1 column missing.
MissingColumn in Database:

```
DOUBLE UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

The Column Name only includes Lower- and Uppercase Characters

Updating the model had no effect.

How can i get the missing column to my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was:

The properties of myColumn were:

```
DOUBLE UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

and it doesn't work with Unsiged Double so i changed the column properties to:

```
DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL
```